# Class templates - Removing an item from a "box" object

Tags: c++, class, templates

I've posted the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66ef9fa0e58eaf52e3a8872b9f3b680b):

This is a data structures course. We are creating a simple PlainBox class and creating member functions that allow us to add and remove items from a "box", check if the box is empty, and check the value of the private data member. I have everything in my assignment completed except one thing: I'm not sure how to create the remove() function so that we can remove an item from a box that already contains something in it.

Here are the instructions: "Add a public method called "remove" to the template class. This method will have no parameters and return a bool value. If the box has an item in it, the item should be removed (make the box empty) and the method should return true (task accomplished). Otherwise, do not modify the box and return false (task could not be performed)."

The remove() function is inside of the PlainBox.cpp file. I'm just confused how I would reset the 'ItemType item' variable to default so that the box is empty. Should I just set 'item' to an empty string? (item = " ";)

```
template<class ItemType>
bool PlainBox<ItemType>::remove()
{
    if (full == true)
    {
        full = false;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

At the bottom of the main.cpp file, I'm testing the remove() function on the secondNumberBox, and checking the private member variable afterwards to see if it's empty.

Here is the PlainBox class for reference:

```
// Declaration for the class PlainBox
class PlainBox: public BoxInterface<ItemType>   // added parent class
{
private:
   // Data field
   ItemType item;
   bool full;

public:
   // Default constructor
   PlainBox();

   // Parameterized constructor
   PlainBox(const ItemType& theItem);

   // Accessor method to get the value of the data field
   ItemType getItem() const;

   // Add method
   bool add(const ItemType& theItem);

   // Remove method
   bool remove();

   // isEmpty method
   bool isEmpty();

}; // end PlainBox
```

I hope I've worded this post correctly, let me know if this doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http:www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Any relevant code must be insisde the post, not in a link. Also make sure you create a [MCVE]

Comment: I've updated my post, let me know if it is acceptable now :)

Comment: `== true` is redundant. Personally I'd make `item` a pointer.

Comment: BTW, templates have to go into header files. You can't implement them in cpp files (if you want to use them in other cpp files).

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused now. [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5bd34dfea77864bcc5083edf18b52459) is a link to the project files provided by the professor. We are supposed to modify them with the new functions and then test them in a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why mess with item? You have a flag (bool full) that denotes whether item is used or not. I am sure you have a method that writes to item when flag is false. Does the writing method care whats in item if bool full is false?

Comment: I suppose you're right. For some reason I thought I was supposed to do more than just set the bool to false. I tend to overthink these things...